# Chrome doesn't always suggest PDF reader when trying to open PDF files from Downloads tab

Tags: chrome-for-android, pdf

I have downloaded a PDF file within Chrome: https://github.com/besp9510/dma_pwm/blob/master/doc/raspberry_pi_dma_pwm.pdf

When I want to open it from the Downloads tab, it offers me ridiculous options instead of the installed PDF reader or office application: GymRun, Automate, and RAR.

[image]

Tried clearing the cache, but that didn't help. Opening the PDF from a file browser directly opens it with the office app.

Why does this happen, and is there anything to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the link to this PDF if it's publicly available? Also, have you tried downloading other PDF files with Chrome?

Comment: This is the PDF: https://github.com/besp9510/dma_pwm/blob/master/doc/raspberry_pi_dma_pwm.pdf

For other files, scenario is the same unfortunately. And I can't uninstall Chrome, only "disable".

Comment: I just did some further testing on Chrome for Android with https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf (PDF file specification, 21.4MB) and https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/en/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-en.pdf (Android Developer Fundamental Course Concepts, 15.8MB), and the Chrome recognized them as PDF files. Could you try them?

Comment: OMG. These are working. Microsoft stepped into github, and ruined all of it just like it did with windows? :D But really, how can Github give a file with PDF extension which then is not being recognized as PDF?

Comment: No, it seems more technical than that, possibly unrelated to Microsoft/GitHub, more about the creation of the PDF file. I'm currently investigating the content of that PDF file, and it seems there's something particular with this (it looks compressed/encrypted), and thus why RAR was shown out of nowhere. I'm currently trying to replicate it with other PDF files with the same characteristic to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: Okay, but still: in case navigating to downloads folder with "My files" or "FX explorer" and touching on the PDF, the default PDF viewer opens without any issue (in this case Office for Android). Anyway, thank you!!

Comment: Github delivers this PDF file with content-type `application/octet-stream` (his is equivalent to "unknown file") instead of the common `application/pdf`. As the possible apps are determined by the content-type Android is unable to show you the correct application list.

Comment: @Robert I guess that makes more sense, and probably affects all PDF files on GitHub...

Comment: And Chrome stores the "content-type" per downloaded file, and later when I select "Downloads", it uses that "content-type" instead of the file's extension? So Chrome maintenances a DB with content-types for all downloaded files?